# Delete a cell in google sheets after changing a dropdown value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

i have 2 columns with dropdown lists in google sheets.
All cells in A3:A26 has the first dropdown list.
I would like that the cell in the Column B gets deleted, if i change the dropdown in Column A.
For example Dropdown in A3 gets changed, Value in B3 gets deleted.
Dropdown in A12 gets changed, Value in B12 gets deleted.

I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: is ,there any relation between these two cells?

Comment: Hello, yes i created a dependet list in the cells in column B from the dropdown value in column A. one of the formula looks like this: =IFERROR(FILTER(LookupHours!$B$1:$B$95,LookupHours!$A$1:$A$95=$A3),"")

Comment: you need to provide one default value as if both have a relation some one gets removed it misses dependency so the value get's removed

Comment: If the information in A3:A26 from another source or will you enter the values manually? In any case, you are going to get a lot of alerts from the data validation if you keep deleting the value that you pick from the list. A common way to solve the same problem is to add conditional formatting to highlight duplicated values.

Comment: I thought of something like this: if the value in A3 gets changed then delete the value in B3. With "spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})". So that only the content will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName() == 'mySheet' && rng.getColumn() == 1 && rng.getRow() > 2) {
    rng.offset(0,1).clearContent()
  }
}
```